# Node.JS, Express & MongoDB Atlas:: Multiple Collections ejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have tried almost all the solutions but couldn't get this fixed.

I'm trying to get multiple collection of data (Mongodb Atlas) onto one ejs file.  But I can't get data onto the rendered ejs sheet. But when I tested with locus I can see all the data received from the database up to res.render("/vendor/show"). But it is not passing onto ejs template.

I have three sets of data sitting on the mongo Atlas:

```
const vendorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    image:String,
    imageId:String,
});

const newpromoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    image:String,
    imageId:String,
    vendor:String,
    description:String,
    sdate:String,
    edate:String,
});
const neweventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    image:String,
    imageId:String,
    description:String,
    vendor:String,
    sdate:String,
    edate:String,
});

    router.get("/vendors/:id",function(req,res) {
        var events={}; //Create Empty event Object
        var promotions={}; //Create Empty promotion Object
        var vendors={};//Create Empty vendor Objext
        Promotion.find({},function (err,allPromotions) {

            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                //Find Collection And Assign It To Object
                promotions=allPromotions;             
            }
        });

        Event.find({},function(err, allEvents) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {      
                events=allEvents;   
            }
        });
        Vendor.find({},function(err,allVendors){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                vendors=allVendors;
                //find order collection and passing it to ejs templates
                res.render("vendors/show",{ event:events, promotion:promotions vendor:vendors});
            }
        });
    });

Show.ejs code as 
<%=vendor.name%> 
<%=promotion.name%> 
<%=event.name%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the async process. In your current code, there are three async processes. Please go through following the link you will definitely get an idea about it.

https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/

if you need more help Don’t hesitate to comment.

Comment: Hi Kets, Thanks for the answer, I managed to get all the data over to show.ejs using callbacks. But now I have another issue. Now I want to filter Promotions and events by vendors. I used if statement but it doesn't filter. Not sure why.

Comment: Hello @Ran, Can you provide me more details regarding it. also If you can share your source code it will save my time to get an understanding of your requirement.

Comment: Hi @Kets Thanks for your time. really appreciate, Not sure how you want to share my code as I'm a newbie for this. I have below included codes for show page and other routes. However, I have seen in an article says it needs to associate data but not sure how. Again thanks

Comment: Just elaborating more about what I'm trying to achieve. *# I have two data collections Event and Promotions also I have another collection for vendors. #I have promotions and events page separately # every promotion and event has vendor as well. #Now when I go to vendor page I need to get all the data belongs to each vendor.  Again thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get all data using the below function. But now I have another issue, need to filter all the Promotions and Events by vendor But it doesn't filter.

Data Schema

```
 const neweventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name:String,
        image:String,
        imageId:String,
        description:String,
        vendor:String,
        sdate:String,
        edate:String,
    });

    const Event = mongoose.model("Event",neweventSchema);

    module.exports = Event;



    //SCHEMA SETUP===============================================================================================================
    const newpromoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name:String,
        image:String,
        imageId:String,
        vendor:String,
        description:String,
        sdate:String,
        edate:String,
    });
    //compile into a model
    const Promotion = mongoose.model('Promotion',newpromoSchema);

    module.exports = Promotion;

  //SCHEMA SETUP===============================================================================================================   
    const vendorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name:String,
        image:String,
        imageId:String,
    });

    const Vendor = mongoose.model("Vendor", vendorSchema);

    module.exports = Vendor;
```

Routes as below

```
router.get("/vendors/:id", function (req, res) {

  Vendor.find({}, function (err, allVendors) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
      // //Find Collection And Assign It To Object

      Event.find({}, function (err, allEvents) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {

          Promotion.find({}, function (err, allPromotions) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {

              //find order collection and passing it to ejs templates
              res.render("vendors/show", {event: allEvents, promo: allPromotions, vendor: allVendors});

            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

EJS Show page But It doesn't get filtered.

```
    <!-- Trying to filter all the events by vendor if event's vendor name == vendor name then show on the show page -->
<%if(event.vendor === vendor.name){%>
<div class = "container-fluid">
    <div class = "row">
        <%event.forEach(function(events){%>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src ="</%=events.image%>" class="rounded" width="304" height="236">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4><%=events.name%></h4>
                        <p class="font-italic font-weight-bold text-muted">
                            <%=events.vendor%>
                        </p>
                        <p><strong>Start Date</strong><%=events.sdate%></p>
                        <p><strong>End Date</strong><%=events.edate%></p>
                    </div>
                    <p>Event Details <br>
                        <%=events.description.substring(0,100)%>
                    </p>
                    <p>             
                        <a href="events/</%=events._id%>", class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Find More </a>
                    </p>
                </div>  
            </div>
        <%})%>
    </div>
</div>
<%}%> 
<!-- //Trying to filter all the promotions by vendor if vendor name= to promotions's vendor name only show in the show page-->
<%if(promo.vendor===vendor.name){%>
<div class = "container-fluid">
    <div class = "row">
        <%promo.forEach(function(promotions){%>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src ="<%=promotions.image%>" class="rounded" width="304" height="236">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4><%=promotions.name%></h4>
                        <p class="font-italic font-weight-bold text-muted"> <%=promotions.vendor%></p>
                        <p><strong>Start Date</strong> <%=promotions.sdate%></p>
                        <p><strong>End Date</strong> <%=promotions.edate%></p>
                    </div>          
                    <p>
                        <%=promotions.description.substring(0,100)%> 
                    </p>
                    <p>             
                        <a href="/promotions/<%=promotions._id %>", class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Find More </a>
                    </p>
                </div>  
            </div>
        <%})%>
    </div>
</div>
<%}%>
```